# Signature image with special character

Tags: ubuntu, console, command-prompt

I have created one python script , i wish to print some signature image made from special character in console.

How to do that ?? Any help would be appreciated ,

e.g,

```
*********************************************
*********    My Name  ***********************
**********    Tag line **********************
```

or some image .

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi I found this code for displaying signature image. It was taken from source-code one of the ubuntu package cowsay.
It displays a cat.

"\n   \\n      \\n        \\n            |\___/|\n          ==) ^Y^ (==\n            \  ^  /\n             )=*=(\n            /     \\n            |     |\n           /| | | |\\n           \| | |*|/\\n        //*// ___/\n               \_)\n  "

-Enjoy